# How do I select a fixed number of elements around (before, and the remainder after) one specific element in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I need a query (issued via php) to select n records (let's say 4) inserted around a given record (n/2 before + n/2 after). If the number of rows inserted before the current element is less than n/2, the remaining records (n-result1) should be those inserted AFTER the current record. A similar thing for the newest records. (select more/all previous records)

Let's say current record id is #1, then the query would give records 2,3,4,5 as a result
If current record is 2, the result would be 1,3,4,5
If current record is 3, the result would be 1,2,4,5
If current record is 6, the result would be 4,5,7,8

Let's say there are 9 elements in the table

If current record is 8, the result would be 5,6,7,9
If current record is last (9), the result would be 5,6,7,8

n would be actually a fixed value, determined via php.
The use of php (if helpful in context -- for example if mysql_last_insert() can be used) is more than welcome

Thank you

Comment: How your record are identified -- and especially ordered? (e.g. a numeric id?) Can you please add your table structure?

Comment: I have an auto_increment ID field for each row. My question goes for any table that has such field.

Comment: Nothing yet. I am considering something that would intricate a mysql_num_rows() in the same line of code, but haven't tried it yet, still looking for options :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting the records with and ID preceding and following some specific ID is not that complicates. The key is to order the records by their IDs and then select only those that are smaller than or greater than the specific ID:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < x ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > x ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 4;
```

This will give you two record sets with the records preceding *x* and following *x* respectively. Then you can union the records depending on the actual size of the record sets to always get at most 4 records.

Comment: I thought of that, but it's that UNION thing that I didn't know about. I'll have a look into it, thank you :)

Comment: @Mihai: Using MySQL’s `UNION` won’t work here as you can’t specify the begin and end of the united set that spans the range you are looking for.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to add a checker to see how many rows are available before current record or after.. which would eat lots of resources if done for most of the pages.. Unless I cache the result periodically.. Oh boy! :) Thank you anyway I'll probably just go with an overall limit on that union and that's it, even if that doesn't answer my original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT ID
FROM Table
WHERE 
ID > '. ($n - 3) .
' AND ID != '. $n .
' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 4'
```

This has the advantage of being one query.

If you want to address the deleted rows issue, you'll actually have to do 2 queries

Comment: Wouldn't this give various result counts depending on the location of the current ID? If ID is the first in my table, it would give 3 results (those located after), while if ID is in the middle of the table, it would give 6 results (3 before + 3 after). I need a constant number of results (let's say 4: 2 before and 2 after). If the current ID is at the beginning at the table and there is only one result BEFORE the current ID, then I would have to add 3 more results inserted AFTER the current ID. That way I would have my constant 4 results. Thank you

Comment: @mihai: is there any case of row deleted like can  the id be 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9  like the id 5 is deleted

Comment: Actually yes, there can be some row IDs that have been removed over time

Comment: @ babonk: This is better, but it would not work properly if some rows have been previously deleted and row ID is not continuous, see above comments.

Comment: suppose the values are 1 3 5 6 7 8.  which values do you want when they enter 5?

Comment: By the way may I ask why you delete ID's? Chances are its a bad idea

Comment: @babonk I delete entire rows, let's say when a user wants to entirely delete their account on the website.
If I have IDs 1 2 4 5 9 11 12 13 and my current row is 9, I would wanna have 4 5 + 11 12